# Grep only newest directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, mingw, command-line-interface

I have a directory of applications, each containing a directory for every version of that application.

```
Applications
    MyApp
        MyApp_0.1
        MyApp_0.2
    MyOtherApp
        MyOtherApp_0.1
        MyOtherApp_0.2
        MyOtherApp_0.3
```

I want to grep this tree, but it takes too long and yields too many old matches, so I only want to check in the highest version of each application.

I'll accept answers using any built-in windows tools, GNU tools, or powershell, but I'm not very familiar with powershell, so a non-powershell answer would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$AppDir = 'C:\apps'
$Apps = Get-ChildItem -Path $AppDir -Directory
Foreach($App in $Apps){
    $HighestVersion = Get-ChildItem -Path $App.FullName | Sort -Descending | Select -First 1
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        App=($App.Name);
        Version=([Version]($HighestVersion -split '_')[1]); #Convert it to a version for easier comparisons
        #Version=(($HighestVersion -split '_')[1]);
        Path=($HighestVersion.FullName)
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up needing to use  `Get-ChildItem | where {$_.PSIsContainer}` instead of `-Directory`, but this got me what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I should have noted that it required [PS 3.0 or 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595). I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Oh, there is one thing though—since it doesn't sort numerically, I ended up with MyOtherOtherApp_0.9.9 being the HighestVersion when there is a MyOtherOtherApp_0.10.0. I searched for .9s and corrected these myself, but do you know a good way to make it sort the versions numerically?

Comment: You can [compare versions in PowerShell](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/01/03/pstip-validating-version-numbers-without-regex/) like this `[version]'0.9.9' -gt [version]'0.10.0'`. That should return `False`. _"One thing to keep in mind when comparing Version objects: 1.0 is evaluated as less than 1.0.0 Similarly 1.0.0 is evaluated as less than 1.0.0.0 If you do not define all the values in the version the undefined values are set to -1 and the comparison takes that into account. Easiest way out of this is probably writing custom function ..."_ -[nohandle](https://twitter.com/nohwnd)